# Is a permit required to camp at Bear Glacier in Seward, Alaska?

Tags: camping, permits, alaska

I'm traveling to Bear Glacier near Seward, AK, USA. We're planning to arrive by water taxi, camp near the glacier, and kayak from there.

Do you need a permit to camp there? I can't find anything online.

Comment: I'm actually not sure if it's in Kenai Fjords NP proper, but it's definitely not the campground at Exit Glacier. I can't find any info online about what park it is in or whether or not you need a permit. I'll call an outfitter tomorrow and post the results.

Comment: Ok thanks everyone! It is indeed in Kenai Fjords NP, but according to the outfitter I'm using (Seward Water Taxi) no permit is required for backpacking.

Answer (score 1):

According to Louie from Seward Water Taxi, no permit is required for backpacking.

Comment: I thought you wanted to camp?